# How to concat 2 columns from different tables on Yii2

Tags: php, model, yii2

I'm trying to rewrite my query in a smart mode, using the facilities of Yii2.

**The original and working method is:**

```
public function getApartamentos() {
     $query = Apartamento::findBySql('select apartamento.id as id, CONCAT(apartamento.numero, \' \', torre.sigla, \' (\', torre.nome,
 \')\') as numero_completo from apartamento left join torre on
 apartamento.torre_fk = torre.id') ;
     return ArrayHelper::map($query->asArray()->all(),'id','numero_completo'); 
}
```

**So, i'm trying to transform the method above on:**

```
public function getApartamentos() {   
     $query = Apartamento::find()
            ->joinWith('torreFk')
            ->select(['apid'=>'apartamento.id','numeroap'=>'CONCAT(apartamento.numero,
 \' \', torre.sigla, \' (\', torre.nome, \')\')']);
     return ArrayHelper::map($query->asArray()->all(),'apid','numeroap'); 
}
```

**But, when i do it, i get some errors:**

```
PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
Undefined index: id
in <?=$form->field($model, 'apartamento_fk')->dropDownList(Apartamento::getApartamentos()) ?>
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException Undefined index: id in 
field($model, 'apartamento_fk')->dropDownList(Apartamento::getApartamentos()) ?>
```

id refers to apartamento_fk...
are you calling the right model in your form?

instead of **joinwith**
better use

```
->leftjoin('torre','apartamento.torre_fk = torre.id')
```

I think it should work